# How to pass a class instance dynamically?

Tags: java

What is wrong with the following android java code

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(PACKAGENAME+"."+className); 
Constructor<?> cons = c.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = cons.newInstance(result);
```

i want it to call a constructor of one parameter.

Comment: What error does your IDE show?

Comment: It is difficult to say without error logs, we even do not know if it does not compile for you (kind of should) or does not run. Please add error messages.

Comment: Hi Rai,this is what I get from the error console: 01-11 07:05:34.348: W/System.err(829): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-11 07:05:34.464: W/System.err(829):  at   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-11 07:05:34.464: W/System.err(829):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)

Comment: More, more stack trace!!! And if it does not fit into comment, put into question.

Comment: What is the type of "result", is it String?